# How to get the local url image path from local disk when browse the image in jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code for preview image and get image name:

```
$("input[type=file]").on("change", function() {
    $("[for=file]").html(this.files[0].name);
    $("#preview").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
})
```

However I want to get the local url of image. For example, the image I choose from `D:/pic.jpg` and I want display this file path. How can I do that? Please help me.

Comment: You can't do it? it is restricted.

Comment: You can't get the local path of the selected file. It used to be possible in older browsers (and IE) however it is now blocked by security.

Comment: oh thank for your answer

Comment: I already tried it years ago. For security purpose, this isn't allowed by the browser.

Comment: thanks , i understand why can't run :D

Answer (score 1):

> No modern browser allow you to get the exact local path of a file.
>   The information your are looking for is limited by the security policy
>   of the browser.